# Why does an img/svg escape the parent container?

Tags: html, css

[image: Example]

In this above image, I am selecting the container that is supposed to contain an svg(dimension of svg are 300x150, while those of the parent div is 50x50). However, I would have expected the svg to at least become smaller to fit into the parent div, rather than just hang out of it, like I see when I try to hover over the element in the DOM as seen in the above picture.

[image: Example 2]

This happens more often, and I wonder if there is a resource/theory that is behind this happening?

Right, right, let's see, code, I kinda thought this was something common. Here's the html and css for that particular section:

HTML:

```
    <section>
<h3 id="about-me">About Myself</h3>

<div class="face-lockup">
    <div class="face-img">

    </div>
    <div class="icon-pencil">{% include icons/icon-pencil.html %}</div>
    <div class="icon-mouse">{% include icons/icon-mouse.html %}</div>
    <div class="icon-browser">{% include icons/icon-browser.html %}</div>
    <div class="icon-video">{% include icons/icon-video.html %}</div>

</div>
<div class="blurb">
    {{ site.data.portfolio.blurb %}}
</div>

<div class="skill-lockup">

{% for skill in site.data.portfolio.skills %}

    <div class="skill-unit">
        <div class="skill-label"> {{  skill.name }}</div>
        <div class="skill-icons skill-{{ skill.value }}">
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
            <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

</div> </section>
```

CSS:

```
    .alt-section
background: $bgcolor

    .thumb-container
max-width: 960px
margin: 0px auto
padding-bottom: 100px
+clearfix

.thumb-unit
    display: block
    width: 25%
    // height: 150px
    background-color: pink
    float: left
    position: relative
    padding-top: 16%
    overflow: hidden

    @media screen and (max-width: 760px)
        width: 50%
        padding-top: 26%

    background:
        position: center center
        repeat: no-repeat
        size: cover

    .thumb-overlay
        +position(absolute, 100% 0px 0px 0px)
        height: 100%
        background: fade-out($accent, 0.5)
        text-align: center
        +transition
        +display(flex)
        +align-items(center)
        +justify-content(space-around)

        strong
            display: block
            padding: 0 20px
            color: white
            font-weight: 300
            text-transform: uppercase
            font-size: 24px
            line-height: 1.2
            padding-bottom: 0px



    &:hover .thumb-overlay
        +position(absolute, 0% 0px null 0px)
```

Comment: Show your CSS / html. Have you applied `width: 100%; height: 100%;` for image/svg?

Comment: How can we debug invisible code?

Comment: I presume what you need is `max-width:100%; max-height:100%;` or maybe, scrutinising the pictures, `overflow:hidden` on the parent.

Comment: Show us your code and we can help you theorize this.

Comment: Sorry, code is added